# -I/path and -L/path put in code

Tags: c, path, compilation, include

I use command to compile:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sphinxbase -I/usr/local/include/pocketsphinx -L/usr/local/lib -lpocketsphinx -lsphinxbase
```

I want compile use only `gcc -o hello hello.c`

Can I put this path in code?

Comment: You must configure your environment and this is useless to do this.

Comment: What you probably want to do, is investigate the "make" command - that'll make compiling your code vastly easier

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of gcc support 'response files', whereby you can put most of those options into a text file, and reference it from the command line:

```
response.txt
-I/usr/local/include 
-I/usr/local/include/sphinxbase 
-I/usr/local/include/pocketsphinx
-L/usr/local/lib 
-lpocketsphinx 
-lsphinxbase
```

> gcc -o hello hello.c @response.txt

But really, I agree with @chris_turner, use a `make` file.